# FileInputStream constructor throws FileNotFoundException when I pass a file to it in IntelliJ

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception, fileinputstream

I'm trying to create a FileInputStream object in IntelliJ however when I instantiate the object by passing the file to the constructor, I get an error message underneath saying that there's an unhandled FileNotFoundException. This stops me from even building my project. Here's the code that I'm working with:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class FileInputTest {
    public void Test() {
        File newFile = new File("RandomFile.txt");
        FileInputStream newStream = new FileInputStream(newFile);
    }
}
```

There's an error message beneath the line where I instantiate the FileInputStream object stating that there's an unhandled FileNotFoundException. Even though there's no error beneath the instantiation of newFile and RandomFile.txt is in the working directory in IntelliJ. The project won't even build because of this, anyone know a fix?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a checked Exception. You need to either declare the method as `throws FileNotFoundException` or surround the code with try/catch. This is a very basic concept in java, you cannot ignore it.

Comment: Research before ask pls.

Comment: Refer to [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) lesson in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

When working with files the compiler raises a checked Exception in your case it is FileNotFoundException. To fix the problem:

```
public class FileInputTest {
    public void Test() {
        try{
            File newFile = new File("RandomFile.txt");
            FileInputStream newStream = new FileInputStream(newFile);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Also try to have a look at Exception Handling and I/O topics.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot! Am familiar with exceptions and I/O but it's the first time that I'm being introduced to the concept of checked vs unchecked exceptions. Somewhat new to Java, so thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Welcome dear and good luck